# How can I set a low input lag custom sensitivity multiplier for my mouse?

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I have two mice, one pricier one that allows me to change DPI with ease (where I use 400 dpi for reasons of habit and muscle memory) and one cheaper one that has no such setting. That cheaper one being a Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 3000 which has a native dpi of 1000.

I want to simulate the sensitivity setting of my pricier mouse on the cheaper one because I travel with the cheaper one yet maintain the same muscle memory of the better mouse. I am aware that there is no perfect lag-less solution due to the nature of the problem (worse sensor with no ability to change the dpi of the sensor) but I want to get the sensitivity to be the same even if there will be lag in the final result.

Reasons why common solutions don't work:

Windows mouse sensitivity slider doesn't work because none of the multipliers are 0.4 (the closest being 0.25 at 3/11 and 0.5 at 4/11).

Registry edits to the mouse sensitivity appear to only be able to increase the multiplier further (could not find anything about reducing it in registry, and didn't want to mess around with it at random for obvious reasons).

AutoHotKey to teleport the mouse back has way too much lag for this purpose.

Current solution right now is using the Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center which allowed me to bind a mouse button (I used middle mouse) to something called "Precision Booster" which allowed me to choose a specific percentage of my normal mouse sensitivity and sets it to that (so I used 40%). However, this solution has 2 downsides that I'd like to get around (that I'm not sure if I can, but that's why I'm asking). With this, I'm no longer able to use the middle mouse button (which is a pretty useful button) and the mouse cursor seems to skip some frames (which I'm really not sure if this would be fixable at all).

I'm asking if there's a better solution, software or driver based that would allow me to use this 0.4 multiplier on the 1000 dpi mouse and still retain the use of the middle mouse button, and ideally with as little input lag as possible (doesn't have to be gone, just reduced as far as possible).